# Custom Keras Metrics Class -> Metric at a certain recall value

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am trying to build a metric that is comparable to the metrics.PrecisionAtRecall class. Therefore, I've tried to build a custom metric by extending the keras.metrics.Metric class.

The original function is *WSS = (TN + FN)/N − 1 + TP/(TP + FN)* and this should be calculated at a certain recall value, for say 95%.

What I have until now is the following:

```
class WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
def __init__(self, recall, name='wss_at_recall', **kwargs):
    super(WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.wss = self.add_weight(name='wss', initializer='zeros')

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_pred_pos = tf.cast(backend.round(backend.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)), tf.float32)
    y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
    y_pos = tf.cast(backend.round(backend.clip(y_true, 0, 1)), tf.float32)
    y_neg = 1 - y_pos
    
    fn = backend.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
    tn = backend.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg)
    tp = backend.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)
    n = len(y_true) # number of studies in batch
    r = tp/(tp+fn+backend.epsilon()) # recall
    self.wss.assign(((tn+fn)/n)-(1+r))

def result(self):
    return self.wss

def reset_states(self):
    # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
    self.wss.assign(0.)
```

How can I calculate the WSS at a certain recall? I've seen the following in tensorflow's own git repository:

```
def __init__(self, recall, num_thresholds=200, name=None, dtype=None):
if recall < 0 or recall > 1:
  raise ValueError('`recall` must be in the range [0, 1].')
self.recall = recall
self.num_thresholds = num_thresholds
super(PrecisionAtRecall, self).__init__(
    value=recall,
    num_thresholds=num_thresholds,
    name=name,
    dtype=dtype)
```

But that is't really possible through the keras.metrics.Metric class

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the definition of the WSS@95 given by this paper :[Reducing Workload in Systematic Review Preparation Using Automated Citation Classification](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1447545/), then we have

> For the present work, we have fixed recall at 0.95 and therefore work saved over sampling at 95% recall (WSS@95%) is:
>
> [image: WSS@95 = (TN+FN)/N - 0.05]

And you could define your update function by :

```py
class WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, recall, name='wss_at_recall', **kwargs):
        if recall < 0 or recall > 1:
            raise ValueError('`recall` must be in the range [0, 1].')
        self.recall = recall
        super(WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.wss = self.add_weight(name='wss', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred_pos = tf.cast(backend.round(backend.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)), tf.float32)
        y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
        y_neg = 1 - y_pos
    
        fn = backend.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
        tn = backend.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg)
        n = len(y_true) # number of studies in batch
        self.wss.assign(((tn+fn)/n)-(1-self.recall))
```

---

One other solution would be to extend from the tensorflow class [`SensitivitySpecificityBase`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1433-L1523) and to implement the WSS as the PresicionAtRecall class is implemented.

By using this class, here's how the WSS is calculated :

- Compute the recall at all the thresholds (200 thresholds by default).
- Find the index of the threshold where the recall is closest to the requested value. (0.95 in that case).
- Compute the WSS at that index.

The number of thresholds is use to match the given recall.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import SensitivitySpecificityBase


class WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall(SensitivitySpecificityBase):
    def __init__(self, recall, num_thresholds=200, name="wss_at_recall", dtype=None):
        if recall < 0 or recall > 1:
            raise ValueError('`recall` must be in the range [0, 1].')
        self.recall = recall
        self.num_thresholds = num_thresholds
        super(WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall, self).__init__(
            value=recall, num_thresholds=num_thresholds, name=name, dtype=dtype
        )

    def result(self):
        recalls = tf.math.div_no_nan(
            self.true_positives, self.true_positives + self.false_negatives
        )
        n = self.true_negatives + self.true_positives + self.false_negatives + self.false_positives
        wss = tf.math.div_no_nan(
            self.true_negatives+self.false_negatives, n
        )
        return self._find_max_under_constraint(
            recalls, wss, tf.math.greater_equal
        )

    def get_config(self):
        """For serialization purposes"""
        config = {'num_thresholds': self.num_thresholds, 'recall': self.recall}
        base_config = super(WorkSavedOverSamplingAtRecall, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Comment: Thank you @Lescurel for your answer. It's indeed from that paper. There is still something wrong in the code, as it returns WSS values as `-1.0500e+00`. Maybe the TensorFlow class `SensitivitySpecificityBase` would fit better. Would I also need to call `@keras_export()` for that?